# how to bind excel data with my lable doc file when move to other pc

Tags: excel

I have created doc(word) file with lables and connect it to my excel data with mailing option in word. Every thing is working file. 
But WHEN I TRANSFER MY FOLDER CONTAINING MY EXCEL DATA FILE AND DOC(LABLE) FILE AND OPEN THE WORD FILE IN OTHER PC IT ASK FOR DATABASE. Is is not possible to bind the datasheet with doc in reference of folder that contains it so everytime when I transfer my folder it doesn't ask for database.?? help

Comment: Are the Word and Excel files in the exact same relative position on the other machine as the original machine?  I would assume that Office would be flexible enough, but if you move the two files to different relative locations, your error would no surprise me.

Comment: both files contains in same folder. but  folder on other pc is at different location then previous PC.